# Override save method force me to save twice in the admin thing

Tags: python, django, django-models

Working on Django1.8.4

So, i got those models :

```
class Occurences(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()

class Serie(models.Model):
    first_occurence = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_occurence = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    occurences = models.ManyToManyField(Occurence, null=True, blank=True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Series, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.first_occurence = self.occurences.order_by['-datetime'].first()
        self.last_occurence = self.occurences.order_by['datetime'].last()
        super(Series, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Working great on manage.py shell.

But as soon as I use the admin interface to make modifications, it doesn't work directly. I have to modify the occurences field, save it, and reload it to resave it once again at the end...

I've already tried to do the super(...).save(...) at the beginning of the save function, well as at the beginning and at the end of it (twice), as well as at the end.

My goal with this is to be able to order the by first_occurence (or last, but one would be enough).

```
Serie.objects.order_by('first_occurence__datetime')
```

because this doesn't work

```
Serie.objects.order_by('occurence__first')
Serie.objects.order_by('occurence__first__datetime')
Serie.objects.order_by('occurence__set__first')
```

I just don't get it :/

Comment: IIRC the admin will _first_ save the main model instance, _then_ the relations (else it couldn't create the relations when it's a new instance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These explicit references to `first_occurence` and `last_occurence` are actually unnecessary, thanks to the Django ORM. All of the functionality that they would provide is available implicitly through the ManyToMany field `occurences`.

If you add a `Meta.ordering` attribute to you `Occurences` model, you can query the first and last. For example:

```
class Occurence(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('datetime',)

class Series(models.Model):
    first_occurence = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_occurence = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    occurences = models.ManyToManyField(Occurence, null=True, blank=True)


my_series = Series.objects.get(...)
first = my_series.objects.earliest()
latest = my_series.objects.latest()
```

Also, given the above, you are able to sort by the occurences to see which have the latest (or earliest) occurences. For example:

```
series_with_latest_occurences = Series.objects.order_by('-occurences__datetime')
series_with_earliest_occurences = Series.objects.order_by('occurences__datetime')
```